# Horizontal Scrollbar Snaps Back To Left Side When Content Is Edited On The "Out Of Bounds" Right Side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, scrollbar

I'm working on an interactive editor in WPF. I use a horizontal scrollbar to edit longer sequences inside the editor, so I can display every block.
When I click something when the scrollbar is scrolled to the right, it snaps back a chunk of the interface (see image). I don't want that. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Image:
[image]

My code:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox Margin="0,0,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding FeederList}">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:FeederControl FeederModel="{Binding}" 
                                             AxisList="{Binding AxisList}" 
                                             DeleteFeederCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}, Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}" 
                                             DeleteCommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>             
        </StackPanel>           
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Try to use `TabIndex` for each item in the view, so after you closed, lets say the last item (ID 5), the UI will recognize it and select/focus now the last item (ID 4). This should prevent this behavior.

Comment: Do I have to implement TabIndex into my ViewModel? Or is it a XAML thing? Isn't there a feature "Scroll only manually" or something?

Comment: `TabIndex` is a WPF property. - You could also simply copy the current offset of the scroller, before you interact on the view, and restore it after the action. (This could end in a little "flicker" effect)

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll try this and report back if it worked.